# Rails - Update hundreds of fields at once, catch transaction failures, return errors but preserve successful transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, optimization, transactions

My use case - 
I have data coming from clients that contain unique ids. I want to use those ids to find their equivalents on the server (for example, I have Object.find_by(client_id: [array of ids]). So far, no problem.

However, I realistically have to update hundreds of objects regularly at a time, and make sure they pass validations. What I would like to do:

Use the above to retrieve a bunch of objects from the server.
Use the incoming params so (if client_id matches retrieved_object_id, update all attributes!)
Validate new objects.
Any objects that failed validation get put into an error block.
The rest, wrap in a transaction and send in a single sql statement.

So, I've learned how to do update_attributes!, which is great because it gives me validation feedback when it throws an error. However, I would have to hit the database, catch the error, and repeat up to hundreds of times, which really doesn't scale well.

I know that a transaction block can make a single sql commit, but if I have 399 valid objects and 1 invalid object, the whole thing gets rolled back.

What's the best practice here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking, but maybe you can filter the objects with `@your_object.valid?`, and then use only the valid objects inside the transaction block.

Note that you probably might want to find the records with `YourModel.find_each` and perform the whole operation in this block to prevent running out of memory if you have a lot of records (although this will imply multiple commits)

Comment: So by using find_each vs where, it will load single objects into memory at a time, at the cost of more DB hits?

Comment: Actually, reading again here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches I don't know if your collections are going to be *that* big to need to use `find_each` or `find_in_batches`

Comment: I'm looking at things like about 500 updates or so at a time, and during peak use it could be thousands of users per minute. :(

Comment: Well. from the Guides, they say: **The find_each and find_in_batches methods are intended for use in the batch processing of a large number of records that wouldn't fit in memory all at once. If you just need to loop over a thousand records the regular find methods are the preferred option.**

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.